# IoT Device Streaming is not connecting

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I am exploring the [Azure IoT Hub Device Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-device-streams-overview) functionality.

I have a C# client connected to the IoT Hub (located in Central US) and active.

[image: IoT Hub - Device connected]

The client is using the following algorithm to wait to an incoming connection (using SDK version 1.29.0-preview-004):

```cs
var buffer = new byte[1024];

using var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

DeviceStreamRequest streamRequest = await deviceClient.WaitForDeviceStreamRequestAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);

if (streamRequest is null)
    return;
```

On the server-side, I have a Azure App Service that is called on a specific endpoint. It retrieves the IoT Hub's connection string

```cs
ServiceClient serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(Constants.IoTHub.ConnectionString, TransportType.Amqp);

DeviceStreamRequest deviceStreamRequest = new DeviceStreamRequest("portal");

DeviceStreamResponse result = await serviceClient.CreateStreamAsync(serialNumber, deviceStreamRequest);
```

I am not able to establish the connection. The `CreateStreamAsync` call times out after 1 minute and the client side never seems to get out of the `WaitForDeviceStreamRequestAsync` call.

I have followed the [troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-device-streams-overview#troubleshoot-via-device-streams-activity-logs) to find out what was is going on but I do not get anything:

[image]

**Question**

Why am I missing that would prevent the IoT Device Streaming from connecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lied in the instance of `DeviceClient` I was using which was built out of information coming from the provisionning service:

```cs
ProvisioningDeviceClient provClient = ProvisioningDeviceClient.Create(Constants.IoTProvisioningService.GlobalDeviceEndpoint, Constants.IoTProvisioningService.IdScope, security, new ProvisioningTransportHandlerHttp());

var result = await provClient.RegisterAsync();

if (result.Status != ProvisioningRegistrationStatusType.Assigned)
    return;

var auth = new DeviceAuthenticationWithTpm(result.DeviceId, security);

--> DeviceClient deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(result.AssignedHub, auth, TransportType.Amqp);
```

Then I was using the `DeviceClient` instance to wait for a request:

```cs
var buffer = new byte[1024];

using var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

--> DeviceStreamRequest streamRequest = await deviceClient.WaitForDeviceStreamRequestAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

However it did not work.

I realized [in the samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-device-streams-echo-csharp) (DeviceClientStreamingSample) that the connection string had to have the Device ID in it which I did not have:

```cs
// String containing Hostname, Device Id & Device Key in one of the following formats:
//  "HostName=<iothub_host_name>;DeviceId=<device_id>;SharedAccessKey=<device_key>"
//  "HostName=<iothub_host_name>;CredentialType=SharedAccessSignature;DeviceId=<device_id>;SharedAccessSignature=SharedAccessSignature sr=<iot_host>/devices/<device_id>&sig=<token>&se=<expiry_time>";

// For this sample either
// - pass this value as a command-prompt argument
// - set the IOTHUB_DEVICE_CONN_STRING environment variable 
// - create a launchSettings.json (see launchSettings.json.template) containing the variable
private static string s_deviceConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("IOTHUB_DEVICE_CONN_STRING");
```

So I stopped reusing the `DeviceClient` instance I got from the provisioning service and built a new one (the code is not production ready - this is a prototype):

```cs
var buffer = new byte[1024];

using var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

var deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(Constants.IoTHub.ConnectionString + $";DeviceId={Constants.Unit.SerialNumber}", TransportType.Amqp);

DeviceStreamRequest streamRequest = await deviceClient.WaitForDeviceStreamRequestAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);

if (streamRequest is null)
    return;

await deviceClient.AcceptDeviceStreamRequestAsync(streamRequest, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

Answer (score 1):

Note, that the Azure IoT Hub Device Streams feature is still in the public preview (over one year). 
You are using the SDKs *1.29.0-preview-004* on device side and *1.27.0-preview-004* on the service side and sample *DeviceStreamingSample* from the *azure-iot-samples-csharp-master* package.

The device streams feature using for handshaking process between the service and device, the same communication concept like for invoking a device method. This handshaking phase can be easy tested with a REST POST request.

For demonstration purpose, I will use my [IoT Hub Tester](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173356/Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester), where the Device Streams feature has been implemented, see more detail in the section Appendix A2.

Step 1. Run the DeviceClientStreamingSample program for your device. You should used the *Transport.Amqp*. Note, that the others failed in my test.

Step 2. Use the REST client tool for generating a POST request. The following url is for my test:

```
https://xxxxxxxxxxx.azure-devices.net/twins/device1/streams/teststream?api-version=2018-08-30-preview
```

headers:

```
accept: application/json
iothub-streaming-response-timeout-in-seconds: 15
iothub-streaming-connect-timeout-in-seconds: 5
Authorization: sas-token
```

payload:
   any or empty

The following screen snippet demonstrated when the POST has been sent to the device1:

[image]

and the following snippet shows stopping a program at the breakpoint after the *WaitForDeviceStreamRequestAsync* method:

[image]

The full handshake and streaming between the device and service (in this case my tester) is shown in the following screen snippet:
[image]

As I mentioned, the Azure IoT Hub Tester has implemented the Device Streams feature, the following screen snippet shows a stream buffer:

[image]

Note, that running the simulated device for *TransportType.Mqtt* doesn't working, the symptom is the same like yours, timeout. It looks like (based on the REST POST response), there is a bug for subscribing a device for the topic such as *$iothub/streams/POST/#*

However, when your device is using a direct MQTT protocol to the IoT Hub, everything is working well, see screen snippet from my tester, where the *device1* is connected to the IoT Hub:
[image]

Once you have the Azure IoT Hub Tester on the screen, you can use it for testing a service SDK for streaming such as the following line from the SDK sample:

```
DeviceStreamResponse result = await _serviceClient.CreateStreamAsync(_deviceId, deviceStreamRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

and the tester will show a *device1* streaming:
[image]

In conclusion, based on my above testing, you should have a successful streaming with the SDKs when the simulated device is configured for *TransportType.Amqp* protocol.

**UPDATE:**

In the case of using a REST client tool, you can see the response from the device handshaking in the headers:

[image]

This response is generated by the following line:

```
await _deviceClient.AcceptDeviceStreamRequestAsync(streamRequest, cancellationTokenSource.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Based on the response headers such as

```
iothub-streaming-is-accepted
iothub-streaming-url
iothub-streaming-auth-token
```

can be established a webSocket streaming communication between the device and service via the IoT Hub. 
Note, that after this point, the simulated device will be failed in the case of using a REST client tool.